# How to check whether a specific website has set SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I've a  problem that  is can we check in php that whether or not a specific web site has set session in the browser to be more specific suppose I visit a site let say "https://example.com" and this site set session on my browser,  How can i check an another my Own
php file that this site has set session on my browser?
If this is not possible then my  specific problem is that I'm working in a client project which is deployed on cpanel and I've created subdomain of it's site now i want that when the main site(domain) set session for a  user how can i check it in the subdomain.
say main domain is "https://example.com" and subdomain is "https://ar.example.com" both site is in php.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Answer (score 0):

Setting the cookie domain variable to set the scope of session at the website level, will ensure the session set in one sub-domain can be accessed by multiple sub-domains including www.

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.domain');
?>
```

Comment: @Khathiraavan Raj But I'm working in the subdomain part, Is there a way to check it in the subdomain?

Comment: try adding the following at end of php.ini file 
    suhosin.session.cryptdocroot=Off
    suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot=Off

Comment: "The goal behind Suhosin is to be a safety net that protects servers from insecure PHP coding practices."